# Indexing every word in a string

Tags: java, string

I want to give a no or index to each word in a string (string will be taken from a txt file may contain special characters or numeric values).
Now what I want to do is, say there's a string "hello, how are you?" then the output should be like:
hello: 1
how: 2
are: 3
you: 4
What I'm trying to do is to separate words by spaces like in above case (It ust also index numbers).

Comment: You don't have a question. We also won't write code for you

Answer (score 2):

You can just split your text on space, removing punctuation along the way, and then iterate through the array and print the indices:

```
String line = "hello, how are you?";
String[] words = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").split("\\s+");

for (int i=0; i < words.length; ++i) {
    System.out.print(words[i] + ":" + i + " ");
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "")` matches any character which is not a lowercase or uppercase letter and removes it
- `split("\\s+")` splits the sentence, using one more whitespace characters as the point for the split

Comment: What is this statement doing? 'line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").split("\\s+");'